# How to make live updated plotly graph in python from SQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to make live update graph with plotly by using python. My code is connected to MySQL server database that gets updated for every 30 seconds. What am I supposed to add in this code? Thank you.

```
import pymysql 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

myMyConn = pymysql.connect(user='ID', password='PW', host='IP', port=#####,charset='utf8', database='###')
myMyCursor = myMyConn.cursor()

        
sql = """
        SELECT X_Axis_CrestFactor, Y_Axis_CrestFactor, Z_Axis_CrestFactor, created_at
        FROM sensor_data
        WHERE info_devaddr = 'FF6CC451';
        """
        
df = pd.read_sql(sql, myMyConn)

x_CrestFactor = df['X_Axis_CrestFactor']
y_CrestFactor = df['Y_Axis_CrestFactor']
z_CrestFactor = df['Z_Axis_CrestFactor']
created_time = df['created_at']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=created_time, y=x_CrestFactor, mode='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=created_time, y=y_CrestFactor, mode='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=created_time, y=z_CrestFactor, mode='lines'))

fig.show()
```

From my original code, all I get is a graph that does not automatically update. How can I update my graph automatically?

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: You need to update your title as well.

Comment: You probably need to use `plotly-dash` – have a look [here](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates)